# R - Problems passing a function to dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to change a column that contains numbers such that instead of the number there will be a name corresponding to that number.

I am using `dplyr` and I have read a table and used `tbl_df` at it:

```
ActivityLabels<-tbl_df(read.table("./UCI HAR Dataset/activity_labels.txt",stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

This gives back this table:

```
> ActivityLabels
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

     V1                 V2
  (int)              (chr)
1     1            WALKING
2     2   WALKING_UPSTAIRS
3     3 WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS
4     4            SITTING
5     5           STANDING
6     6             LAYING
```

Now I have a small data frame with numbers which I would like to replace with the character values using the V2 column.

I wrote the following function:

```
GetActivityNamesFromActivityNumbers <- function(ActivityNumbers)
{
  as.character(ActivityLabels[ActivityNumbers,2])
}
```

And manually it works:

```
> GetActivityNamesFromActivityNumbers(1)
[1] "WALKING"
> GetActivityNamesFromActivityNumbers(2)
[1] "WALKING_UPSTAIRS"
> GetActivityNamesFromActivityNumbers(c(1,2))
[1] "c(\"WALKING\", \"WALKING_UPSTAIRS\")"
>
```

but the following `mutate` does not work as I expect:

```
> sample
Source: local data frame [6 x 1]

  ActivityName
         (int)
1            5
2            5
3            5
4            5
5            5
6            5
> sample %>% mutate(ActivityName = GetActivityNamesFromActivityNumbers(ActivityName))
Source: local data frame [6 x 1]

                                                               ActivityName
                                                                      (chr)
1 c("STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING")
2 c("STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING")
3 c("STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING")
4 c("STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING")
5 c("STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING")
6 c("STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING", "STANDING")
>
```

What am I doing wrong ? when I try to pass functions such as `log`,  `mutate` works like I expect it, but with my function it does not.

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple merge

```
setNames(ActivityLabels, c("ActivityName", "ActivityNameLong"))
merge(sample, ActivityLabels, by = "ActivityName")
```

The reason for your behaviour is because `ActivityLabels` is a `tbl_df`. This results in `mutate` returning a data.frame, instead of an element of the data.frame. From the *Methods*:

> [
>
> Never simplifies (drops), so always returns data.frame

So it returns a data frame for every row, instead of a single value.

Comment: The answer above is correct. To answer the unasked question ("how am I supposed to do this in a dplyr chain then?"), use a `left_join()` instead of mutate and your function:

    sample %>%
        left_join(ActivityLabels, by = c('ActivityName' = 'V1') %>%
        select( ActivityName = V1)